# How to spell numbers in TCL?

Tags: localization, tcl

I thought this might be possible in TCL with [format](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/format.htm), but I'm not seeing how. My requirement is a spell_number function, i.e. given the number 456,789, output the string **four hundred and fifty six thousand, seven hundred and eighty nine**.

Ideally I'd like to be able to pass this function a locale, and have the output localised, but English will do for now!

Any suggestions?

Comment: see https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Number_names

Comment: Thanks. Looks like a good start!

Comment: Whole bunch of them here https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Bag+of+number%2Ftime+spellers